# Edit style of data-title like, for example, position

Tags: html, css, html-dataset

I don't know if I am making this question right since I searched for some information but didn't find what I was looking for.
I have a long text in a data-title (it belongs to a photo gallery). The text is just at the bottom of the modal image but I'd like putting it on the top and I find no way to edit or change the position of the data-title. Maybe in the next image it looks simpler:

[image: Modal image the way it looks at the moment and the result I'm looking for]

The html follows the next structure:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 item">
    <a href="#" data-lightbox="photos" data-title="This is a text">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="#">
    </a>
</div>
```

I think in this case it's not necessary to edit javascript but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: do you have access to the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dataset properties of Elements aren't uniform and therefore you can't just pick a random name and hope it'll work. Different libraries handle things very differently. I think that you're using [this](https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) lightbox library. Its docs don't mention anything about an ability to change the description position. Looking at a HTML structure generated by the aforementioned library you could apply the following CSS and hope it works:

```
.lightbox {
     display: flex !important;
     flex-direction: column-reverse !important;
}
```

This solution is somewhat bad and even a minor change in the library can break everything. Also, this moves the entire desc container to the top. I think it's the most you can achieve without modifying the library's behaviour. If you really want to customize those elements you  should implement your own lightbox or find a library that allows you to make such changes.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, TeraWattHour. Now the captions are on the top. I don't know why the close button (lg-close in the library) has stopped working but I guess this is the only solution I have at the moment since, as you said, I've been using a library.
I use many libraries cos it's an easy way to avoid problems (well, it depends on which ones) when making things work.
I'm making tryes with the close button. Maybe the problem is related to the z-index or the layers.
Many thanks for your help